# How to update a field of dynamic Elements (Input ID & Name)

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to update an amount to a field which having the below elements. I am no sure what is the code to use as the input id and name are not fixed and it change every time i access it. It doesn't give me any error message but the field is not being updated after I ran the codes.

```
`<div class="field-item dataValueWrite">
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td nowrap="" align="left">
      <div id="93497ErrorCUSTOM" class="" style="display:none;"><span class="" errid="" title="Please enter a valid amount" id="93497PegaRULESErrorFlag"></span></div>
      <input id="93497" name="93497" onchange="changedInputAmountInCurrencyDisplay(this , '2' , '.' , '.' , ',' , 'false' ); " class="rightJustifyStyle" type="text" size="10" value="" data-changed="false"><script> formatCurrencyBeforeLoad(document.getElementById('93497'),'2','.', 'false'); 
      </script><input id="93497HIDDEN" name="$PAcqCaseCreation$pMessageAmountUSD" type="hidden" value="0.00">
      <script> 
         formatCurrencyBeforeLoad(document.getElementById('93497HIDDEN'),'2', '.' , 'false'); 
      </script> 
        &nbsp;USD  
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>`
```

Below is the code that I created so far:

```
Sub Test()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

IE.navigate "intranet"
IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

Set doc = IE.document

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim fileLink26 As String
Dim fileLink19 As String

Sheets("Case").Select
lastRow = Sheets("Case").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastRow

doc.contentDocument.querySelector("[onclick='CreateAcqCase();']").Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

fileLink26 = Cells(i, 26)
fileLink19 = Cells(i, 19)

    If fileLink26 = "" And fileLink19 = "CB" And Cells(i, 10).Value = "USD" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim DispStg2 As Object
    Do While DispStg2 Is Nothing
    Set DispStg2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("input[value='FirstCB']")
    DoEvents
    Loop
    DispStg2.Click

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("input.rightJustifyStyle").Item(2).Value = Sheets("Case").Range("k2") '>> This is where I stuck cause nothing happen after this code ran

End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The line on which you are stuck is assigning the value to Range in Excel Sheet. Does your Excel file has that value from the web page? You said nothing is working after that line. we need that code which is not working to see whether there is anything which caused this issue. It can be possible that your code is not able to find the control in an Iframe. Try to print the value in console to check it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - All the codes ran successfully except for the row that I highlighted. By the way, I have amended that row a bit as my intention is to update the field with the value indicated on my excel but it still doesn't work. I tried to print the value in console to check but it came back blank ( fac = doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("input.rightJustifyStyle" ).Item(2).Value  Debug.Print fac). Hope you could help caused I tried searching the codes for days but still no result.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentDocument.querySelector("input.rightJustifyStyle").Item(2).Value = Sheets("Case").Range("k2")
```

From your above sample code, it looks like you are trying to set the value of a second input element which has class name **rightJustifyStyle** in an iframe.

You can refer an example below.

```
Public Sub demo()
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

        ie.Navigate2 "D:\Backup20190913\tests\354.html"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ie.Navigate2 ie.document.querySelector("iframe").src

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ie.document.querySelector("input.rightJustifyStyle:nth-of-type(2)").Value = "Test value..."


        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop
        ie.Quit

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know If I misunderstood anything. I will try to correct myself.

Comment: Yes, you are right but nothing happen after ran the code. In the same iframe there are other fields to update but all are having fixed elements value except for this particular field.

Comment: Did you get similar result with above example?

Comment: Yes, I have modified the code according to your sample by adding :nth-of-type(2) into the row that I am facing issue but nothing happen.

Comment: Please also try to use  ie.Navigate2 ie.document.querySelector("iframe").src in your test.

Comment: I have tried that yesterday but it still gave me the same result.

Comment: Not sure, whether it is setting the value to any other control as it is not giving any error. Another thing you can try is to pass the full path of that control in query selector. If the site is not confidential then you can share the URL. We can try to test the example with that site. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I wish I can share with you the URL just that it is id and password protected. By the way may I know what do you mean by pass the path of that control in query selector? Just for your info the reason I use the class name as it is the shortest and unchanged attribute Element for that textbox.

Comment: What I mean is try to locate the element like in this example. querySelector("div > div >p >input") Test with it to check whether it helps or not..

Comment: I tried Debug.Print with querySelector("div > div >p >input") yet it still give me empty result.

Comment: It looks like we need a site to test the issue. Without it, we are not able to give any solid suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.